# Pairwise comparisons on mcglm joint model in r

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons

Using the mcglm package in r, I have been able to get pairwise comparisons from single-DV models but have not figured out how to get pairwise comparisons for an IV according to both DVs in a joint model.

```
df <- data.frame("r1" = rnorm(75), 
                 "r2" = rnorm(75), 
                 "p1" = c("f1","f2","f3"))
```

### single-DV models

```
mat <- mc_id(df) 
e1 <- r1 ~ p1
e2 <- r2 ~ p1
m1  <- mcglm(linear_pred = c(e1), matrix_pred = list(resp = mat),
             control_algorithm = list(correct = FALSE), data = df)
m2  <- mcglm(linear_pred = c(e2), matrix_pred = list(resp = mat),
             control_algorithm = list(correct = FALSE), data = df)
```

### joint model

```
joint <- mcglm(linear_pred = c(e1,e2), 
               matrix_pred = list(resp = mat,resp = mat), 
               control_algorithm = list(correct = FALSE),  
               data = df)
```

### Pairwise comparisons from single-DV model

```
x = data.frame(df$p1);colnames(x)<-"x"
y = fitted(m1)
y=matrix(y); colnames(y)<-"y"
dat <- cbind(y,x)
m1.anova<-aov(y~x,data=dat)
TukeyHSD(m1.anova,"x")`
```

Does anyone have a solution for the joint model?

Comment: Firstly, because there are now multiple independent and dependent variables, you need to define your contrasts over specific variables in both groups. I haven't worked with mcglm in a while, but I'd check the documentation. Can it interface with emmeans? You can also always calculate the estimated marginal means (predict) and run the t-tests yourself.

Comment: mcglm doesn't interface with emmeans, nor does it have a predict() function - although it might have something similar to predict that I'm not familiar with. As for contrasts, there is a function called mc_initial_values that the package claims allows the user to obtain initial values, including contrasts, but there are no examples of how to use it and I've had no luck thus far.

Comment: Initial values is simply a function for initializing the model parameters BEFORE fitting; it won't be much use to you after fitting. It looks like you can get predictions with the fitted function. If that doesn't work, you can build then yourself from basic linear algebra operations. Check the mcglm white paper for a explanation.

Comment: I think my example above shows that I can get pairwise comparisons from the fitted() function, but as the question states, I don't know how that would work with two DVs. As for building them from basic linear algebra operations, that would be one option for how to answer this question. Alas, I'm not a statistician and there are 0 references to pairwise comparisons in any of the mcglm publications.

Comment: Now I'm confused: do you want to measure the overall effect of your independent variables on all your dependent variables. If so, you can just run `anova` on the `mcglm` model object and it should perform a Wald-type test. I assumed you wanted particular comparison (the difference between level 0 of factor 1 and level 1 of factor 1 with respect to one of the variables). If you want to latter, it should be enough to use t-tests between means and then apply a correction. TukeyHSD is nearly identical to a t-test and can be replaced by independent t-tests with an appropriate correction.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the mcglm package has no support for multivariate multiple comparison tests. It is an on going work with my colleague (Guilherme Parreira) and a preliminary code is available on github https://github.com/guilhermeparreira/code/blob/master/code/comp.R. However, the code is not completely generic, thus probably you have to adapt it to your problem.
I have a paper under review explaining the methodology behind multivariate multiple hypothesis tests using the mcglm package, but it is a simple extension of the standard Wald-type test. It should be available soon.
Thanks for your interest in the mcglm package.

Best wishes.